# How to request energy field output in ABAQUS Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I m trying to extract energy at each integration point in Abaqus. I can do it for stresses or strains but i cant do for the energetical quantities. The obtained error is : “KeyError: 'ELEN'”, but in Abaqus it is the good keyword… Below it is my code to extract it :

```
from odbAccess import *
import numpy as np

odb = openOdb(path='C:/Desktop/Fish1.odb')

# lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-2'].frames[-1]
lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]

topCenter = \
odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1']
stressField = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['ELEN']


field = stressField.getSubset(region=topCenter,
position=INTEGRATION_POINT, elementType = 'CPS3')
fieldValues = field.values

sortie = open('C:/Users/tests.txt', 'w')
sortie.write('Eleme \t Integ \t\t PE11 \t\t\t PE22 \t\t\t PE12 \n')


for v in fieldValues:
    sortie.write('%-10.2f'% ( v.elementLabel))
    if v.integrationPoint:
        sortie.write('%-10.2f'% (v.integrationPoint))
        sortie.write('%-10.3f\t\t %-10.3f\t\t %-10.3f\t\t %-10.3f\t\t \n'% (v.data[0], v.data[1], v.data[2], v.data[3]))

sortie.close()
```

Comment: did you request `ELEN` output when you ran the analysis?

Comment: Yep of course! :)

Comment: see what `lastFrame.fieldOutputs.keys()` shows.  You should review your `.dat` and `.msg` files as well in case the request was invalid for some reason there should be a warning about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have already checked in Abaqus Viewer whether the FieldOutput ELEN is available there.

ELEN is a whole element variable, so you can't extract it at integration points, because it is not available there.

```
from odbAccess import *
import numpy as np

odb = openOdb(path='C:/Desktop/Fish1.odb')
lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]

topCenter = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1']
stressField = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['ELEN']

field = stressField.getSubset(region=topCenter, elementType = 'CPS3')
fieldValues = field.values
```

Even though it is not really the solution you asked for, i hope this will help.